# hibernate oracle 11g error

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to develop one simple hibernate application. But I'm getting "Logon denied" exception though I have provided correct username and password. I'm using Oracle 11g and hibernate 5.2.12.

**Below is the exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at org.ambar.hibernatedemo.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:384)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:657)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:433)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:471)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:365)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:812)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:411)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:547)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:29)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:556)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 29 more
```

**Below is the hibernate.cfg.xml file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe</property>
    <property name="username">Ambar</property>
    <property name="password">TIGER</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">5</property>  
    <mapping class="org.ambar.hibernatedemo.UserDetails" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: not scott/tiger ? ;-)

Comment: nope. I have specified my own credentials at the time of installation

Answer (score 1):

Double check the username/password

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

<property name="username">Ambar</property>
<property name="password">TIGER</property>
```

Easiest way to check is grab [SQLcl](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html) and connect
IF the user and password were created case sensative

```
 sql "Ambar"/"TIGER"@//127.0.0.1:1521:xe
```

IF the user and password were NOT created case sensative

```
 sql Ambar/TIGER@//127.0.0.1:1521:xe
```

Comment: Checking password in lowercase is not a good test for a password in uppercase.

Comment: True just edited to add  a case and non-case option.

Comment: I use same credentials to connect to oracle thru command line and they are working perfectly fine.

Comment: Is your user or passwd case sensitive ? if so make sure the properties match